# Dynamically adding input fields in an Angular application

Tags: angularjs

I have a standard Angular controller invoked with appropriate routing:

```
when('/admin/foo/new',{
            controller:FooNewCtrl,
            templateUrl: 'frontend/partials/admin/foo-new.html'
        }).
```

FooNewCtrl, nothing in it:

```
function FooNewCtrl($scope) {
}
```

In foo-new.html I have a section where I want the user to be able to dynamically add and delete input fields:

```
<label>Fields<a href="?????"><i class="foundicon-plus"></i></a></label>
  <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
     <input type="text" id="field.id"/><a href="????">delete</a>
  </div>
```

I do not know how to make this happen. Note that I have a link, with a "plus" icon, used to add the new field, then when the field is displayed, a link that would delete it.
I do not know how to control "fields" with a controller and keep the user on the page.
I'm looking for a push in some direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ng-repeat you're basically saying 'for every field in the fields collection, located in this scope'.

```
function FooNewCtrl($scope) {
     //What you're iterating over in your ng-repeat
     $scope.fields = [];

     //Declare a function on the scope that you can reference from your template
     $scope.addField = function(){

         $scope.fields.push(1); //Push a new object into the fields
     };

}
```

So yeah you'd add an ng-click event to your  element (parent of your icon), that pushed a new field onto fields.

```
<label>Fields<a ng-click="addField()"><i class="foundicon-plus"></i></a></label>
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
 <input type="text" id="field.id"/><a href="????">delete</a>
 </div>
```

Clicking the plus icon should now dynamically add your inputs. I'll leave removing them to you.